# Rspec rerunning all tests with --only-failures, even passed ones

Tags: ruby, rspec

We have a a Ruby gem that wraps rspec for our selenium tests.  I am trying to implement retry logic by re-running the failures from previous runs, but on the 2nd run it just retries everything, and I think it's because it's not loading the spec_helper on the 2nd run, which contains the `example_status_persistence_file_path` location.

I added a debugging `puts` statement in the spec_helper, and you'll see it's not getting called twice, only once.  However, I'm also not getting the error that appears when `example_status_persistence_file_path` isn't set, so I don't know what to do.

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "logs/LO_RunResults.txt"
end
```

my_spec.rb

```
it "should pass" do
  expect(true).to be true
end

it "should fail" do
  expect(false).to be true
end
```

rspec_runner.rb

```
test_results_file = "#{File.expand_path(Dir.pwd)}/logs/RunResults.txt"
File.delete(test_results_file) if File.exist?(test_results_file)

args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, $stderr, $stdout)

# RunResults.txt is generated from previous run

args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation --only-failures)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, $stderr, $stdout)
```

When I run `ruby rspec_runner.rb`, this is my output:

```
#################### Running spec_helper ####################

Test Suite - my_spec
  Positive Tests
    should pass
    should fail (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail
     Failure/Error: expect(false).to be true
     
       expected true
            got false
     # ./spec/my_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.06265 seconds (files took 0.71696 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/my_spec.rb:58 # Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail

Run options: include {:last_run_status=>"failed"}

Test Suite - my_spec
  Positive Tests
    should pass
    should fail (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail
     Got 2 failures:

     1.1) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be true
          
            expected true
                 got false
          # ./spec/my_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be true
          
            expected true
                 got false
          # ./spec/my_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail
     Got 2 failures:

     2.1) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be true
          
            expected true
                 got false
          # ./spec/my_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     2.2) Failure/Error: expect(false).to be true
          
            expected true
                 got false
          # ./spec/my_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03786 seconds (files took 0.79882 seconds to load)
4 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/my_spec.rb:58 # Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail
rspec ./spec/my_spec.rb:58 # Test Suite - my_spec Positive Tests should fail


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `RSpec.clear_examples` between the two runs in order to force RSpec to reload the examples:

```
test_results_file = "#{File.expand_path(Dir.pwd)}/logs/RunResults.txt"
File.delete(test_results_file) if File.exist?(test_results_file)

args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, $stderr, $stdout)

RSpec.clear_examples

# RunResults.txt is generated from previous run

args = %w(-r spec_helper --order defined --format CustomFormatter --format documentation --only-failures)
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, $stderr, $stdout)
```

Documentation is here for reference: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec.clear_examples.

> Used to ensure examples get reloaded between multiple runs in the same
> process and ensures user configuration is persisted.
>
> Users must invoke this if they want to clear all examples but preserve
> current configuration when they use the runner multiple times within
> the same process.